# Balão de ajuda/informação

Tags: javascript, html

Gostaria de saber, basicamente, como se faz esses balões que **aparecem quando passamos o mouse** por cima do ícone:

[image: balao]

- Ele pode aparecer em qualquer posição da tela correto!?
- Mas como alinhá-lo com o ícone?

Comment: Aqui onde trabalho o proxy não deixa ver a imagem, mas pela descrição, creio que você quer dizer `tooltip` (?)

Comment: @MarceloBoni se for esse `tooltip`, ele é estilizado. Tem como fazer isso!?

Comment: Se eu conseguisse ver a imagem já ajudaria muito pra te dar uma resposta correta kkkk vou tentar visualizar pelo celular

Comment: Se estiver utilzando **Bootstrap** já vem com tooltip é só incorporá-lo.

Comment: Como pode ver [aqui](https://codepen.io/tag/tooltip/) existem vários exemplos de `tooltip` estilizados.

Comment: [Um exemplo complexo de tooltip com dependência 0 de js](https://codepen.io/RoughKnight/pen/Qmpwex)

Comment: @Leandro queria o básico, pra entender como funciona mesmo, como estilizar, etc

Comment: @MarceloBoni realmente é estilização do `tooltip` ? Esse `tooltip` não é do browser!?

Comment: Downvoter, diga o motivo do seu -1 que irei melhorar a pergunta! (Cada cara mala bicho)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se vc estiver utilizando **bootstrap** siga a resposta do Netinho Santos, se não estiver utilizando dá para criar e estilizar com **CSS** puro mesmo.

```css
p {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 50px;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

p:hover ~ span {
  display: block;
}

span {
  display: none;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: red;
  width: 13%;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  position: relative;
  top: -100px;
  left: 60%;
}
```

```html
<p>TEXTO</p>

<span>Informações</span>
```

Comment: Leandro, eu gostaria de saber como faz sem framework, pois tenho ferramentas web com estilos mínimos, então não convém usar um framework só para isso. Mas agradeço a dica!

Comment: Mas o exemplo que dei aqui não tem framework é CSS puro.

Comment: Opa ! Agora que entendi! Boa! isso mesmo!

Comment: Aí eu estilizo e posiciono o balão onde quiser, certo !?

Comment: Aí vc vai estlizando ele como quiser, isto, no left, no top, no background-color se quiser outra cor, no color para a cor do texto, etc...

Comment: Leandro, pode me explicar como funciona esse `~` em `h1:hover ~ span`? Nunca tinha visto isso! Queria entender melhor!

Comment: Aliás, eu passo o mouse onde está posicionado o `span` ele aparece também... não deveria ser só no "TEXTO"?

Comment: Ali estou dizendo quando o texto ou seja `h1` estiver com o **hover** ou seja quando estiver com o mouse em cima ele pega **`~`** (para isto que serve o til) o elemento `span` e aplica os efeitos.

Comment: É que fiz um exemplo bem simples mesmo, isto ocorre pq o **span** está na mesma altura ou seja dentro do **h1** aí ele sofre o efeito hover tbm. Mas aí é só posicioná-lo diferente ou trocar a tag do texto, tem várias formas de fazer.

Comment: Editei a resposta, blza. Agora só quando passa o mouse no texto aciona o tooltip.

Comment: Ele está pegando a linha toda...

Comment: Sim pq é uma tg **p** por padrão pega a linha toda.

Answer (score 3):

Utilize `tooltip` já incluído no Bootstrap, vê [documentação](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/tooltips/). 
Use o atributo `data-placement` para definir a posição da dica na parte superior, inferior, esquerda ou no lado direito do elemento:

> Dica: Você também pode usar o atributo data-placement  com um valor "auto", que permitirá ao navegador decidir a posição da dica de ferramenta. Por exemplo, se o valor for "auto left", a dica de ferramenta será exibida no lado esquerdo quando possível, caso contrário, à direita.
>   Fonte: https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_tooltip.asp

```js
$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<i class="fa fa-info-circle" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Atenção!"></i>
```

Comment: Netinho, eu gostaria de saber como faz sem framework, pois tenho ferramentas web com estilos mínimos, então não convém usar um framework só para isso. Mas agradeço a dica!

Comment: Eu que agradeço. Segue um exemplo com CSS puro. Caso seja o que queres, eu edito a resposta e incluo o código. https://jsfiddle.net/s7ph5kcu/3/ 
Att.